# is there a gem to create Twitter-like follow or is that a trivial :has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database-design, twitter

was wondering if someone wanted a Twitter-like follow feature, is there a gem?  I know there is one to handle "friends" but is following simply has_many or is there a gem which would help with implementation (including the ajax/jquery portion?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a plugin (not a gem), but it's rails3 compatible and is quite complete:
https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/

Comment: yes this looks fantastic!  I am trying to plug it in right now....it is the type of solution I was looking for....haven't checked to see the javascript aspect though....

Comment: @Adam...yep, this looks good on the backend....looking for how people implemented js.erb on the back to toggle UI

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer step by step, first without Javascript, later using javascript.
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top

Comment: thanks -- I will look into this for the UI , @adam rubin's answer was what I was looking for in the backend/model

Answer (score 0):

It could be implemented as a simple `has_many`, along with some simple POSTs to the server to actions 'follow' and 'unfollow' which would add/remove rows in the associated table.

Comment: is there an example that I can use somewhere, particularly managing the .js.erb's showing status toggled from following or unfollowed?  I get it conceptually, just think oher people may have already done it and done it better....

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) gem to do follow exactly like Twitter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [acts_in_relation](https://github.com/kami30k/acts_in_relation) gem. I wrote the howto in my [blog post](http://wiredify.com/shohey1226/logs/Implement-follow-function-with-acts_in_relation-Gem-on-Rails-app).