# How do I set up a directed many-to-many self-join using :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relationship

I'm setting up a Rails project for a client, and they want Users (a model) to be able to follow each other (as in Twitter). They also want to be able to keep track of when one user started following another.

Since I need to keep track of the creation date, I figured, a `has_many X, :through => Y` relation would be the way to go, so the Y will keep track of the date it was created.

I have my Follow model set up:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :actor_id, :observer_id, :follower, :followee
  attr_readonly :actor_id, :observer_id, :follower, :followee

  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :observer_id
  belongs_to :followee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :actor_id

  validates_presence_of :follower, :followee
  validates_uniqueness_of :actor_id, :scope => :observer_id
end
```

The question is how do I set up the relations in the User model?

Ideally I'd like it to have the following:

- `:follows` would be the associated Follow objects where self is the follower (observer_id)
- `:followed` would be the associated Follow objects where self is the followee (actor_id)
- `:following` would be the associated User objects where self is the follower (observer_id)
- `:followers` would be the associated User objects where self is the followee (actor_id)

I'm not sure how to write the `has_many :through` parts, though? Should I be using `:source => X` or `foreign_key => X`? And which key (actor_id or observer_id) should I put in each?

Edit: I'm currently doing this

```
has_many :follows, :foreign_key => :observer_id
has_many :followed, :class_name => 'Follow', :foreign_key => :actor_id
has_many :following, :class_name => 'User', :through => :follows, :source => :followee, :uniq => true
has_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :through => :follows, :source => :follower, :uniq => true
```

and it's *mostly* working. All of them except `:followers` work fine, but `user.followers` is doing something weird. It *seems* like it's checking whether user is followING someone, and if they are then `user.followers` returns an array containing only user; if they're not, it returns an empty array.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: There's a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773523/is-there-a-gem-to-create-twitter-like-follow-or-is-that-a-trivial-has-many that references both a tutorial and a gem for this pattern. Might want to check it out.

Comment: why dont you just try it?

Comment: @Lichtamberg: I've tried a couple different ways. What I'd really like, though, is to not just know what the correct answer is but also understand *why* it's the correct answer via improved understanding of what the different keywords do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the correct format:

```
has_many :follows, :foreign_key => :observer_id
has_many :followed, :class_name => 'Follow', :foreign_key => :actor_id
has_many :following, :class_name => 'User', :through => :follows, :source => :followee, :uniq => true
has_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :through => :followed, :source => :follower, :uniq => true
```

For Rails newbies, the `:uniq => true` is important (as I discovered while doing this) because it keeps `has_many X, :through => Y` relations from returning duplicates (that is, without it, you might get multiple distinct objects, each with their own object ID, all referring to the same record/row).